# h5py order of dataset by dataset name

Tags: python, hdf5, h5py

I am creating an h5 files with 5 datasets ['a160'],['a1214']

How can I make it so that the datasets will be sorted by the dataset name..

For example when I do h5dump on my file I get:

```
HDF5 "jjjj.h5" {
GROUP "/" {
   DATASET "a1214" {
      DATATYPE  H5T_IEEE_F32BE
      DATASPACE  SIMPLE { ( 1, 19 ) / ( H5S_UNLIMITED, 19 ) }
      DATA {
      (0,0): 160, 0, 165, 4, 2.29761, 264, 4, 1.74368, 1, 0, 17, 193, 0, 0,
      (0,14): 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
      }
   }
   DATASET "a160" {
      DATATYPE  H5T_IEEE_F32BE
      DATASPACE  SIMPLE { ( 3, 19 ) / ( H5S_UNLIMITED, 19 ) }
      DATA {
      (0,0): 263, 0, 262, 7, 4.90241, 201, 34, 0.348432, 1, 0, 29, 11, 0, 0,
      (0,14): 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
      }
   }
```

But I want it to be ordered by the dataset name, I need h5dump to output

```
HDF5 "jjjj.h5" {
GROUP "/" {
   DATASET "a160" {
      DATATYPE  H5T_IEEE_F32BE
      DATASPACE  SIMPLE { ( 3, 19 ) / ( H5S_UNLIMITED, 19 ) }
      DATA {
      (0,0): 263, 0, 262, 7, 4.90241, 201, 34, 0.348432, 1, 0, 29, 11, 0, 0,
      (0,14): 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
      }
   }

   DATASET "a1214" {
      DATATYPE  H5T_IEEE_F32BE
      DATASPACE  SIMPLE { ( 1, 19 ) / ( H5S_UNLIMITED, 19 ) }
      DATA {
      (0,0): 160, 0, 165, 4, 2.29761, 264, 4, 1.74368, 1, 0, 17, 193, 0, 0,
      (0,14): 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default `h5dump` sorts HDF5 files' groups and attributes by their names in ascending order:

```
-q Q, --sort_by=Q    Sort groups and attributes by index Q
-z Z, --sort_order=Z Sort groups and attributes by order Z

Q - is the sort index type. It can be "creation_order" or "name" (default)
Z - is the sort order type. It can be "descending" or "ascending" (default)
```

The problem in this case is that "a160" is considered greater than "a1214" because that's how dictionary sorting works ('a12' < 'a16').

There's no change you can make to the internal structure of the HDF5 file to force `h5dump` to sort these data structures in a different order.  However, you could zero-pad your names like so:

```
a0040
a0160
a1214
```

and then the standard dictionary sort will output the file the way you want.